# Unsure why I'm getting key error when merging

Tags: python, pandas

Getting the following key error when trying to merge. Don't believe I have duplicates in either when I try that approach, however.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
train_users = pd.read_csv("train_users_2.csv")
test_users = pd.read_csv("test_users.csv")
df = pd.concat((train_users, test_users), axis = 0, ignore_index = True, sort = True)
df_without_NDF = df[df['country_destination']!='NDF']
sessions = pd.read_csv("sessions.csv")
session_booked = pd.merge(df_without_NDF, sessions, how = 'left', left_on = 'id', right_on = 'user_id')
sessions.rename(columns = {'user_id': 'id'}, inplace=True)
secs_elapsed.reset_index(inplace=True)
sessions_secs_elapsed = pd.merge(sessions_data, secs_elapsed, on='id', how='left')
df = pd.merge(df, sessions_secs_elapsed, on='id', how = 'left')
```

Error:

```
----> 1 sessions_secs_elapsed = pd.merge(sessions_data, secs_elapsed, on='id', how='left')

-> 1379             raise KeyError(key)
   1380 
   1381         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'id'
```

To be fully and minimally testable, my data sources come from the following: https://github.com/FraPochetti/Airbnb/blob/master/data/train_users_2.csv https://github.com/FraPochetti/Airbnb/blob/master/data/test_users.csv
https://github.com/jafriyie1/Airbnb-New-User-Bookings/blob/master/sessions.csv.zip

Comment: you have a lot of dataframes with similar name. on the line of error, I did not see `sessions_data` defined.

Comment: `print .columns()` on both your frames, one of them has a mismatching name.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that one of the dataframes doesn't have 'id' column. Make sure that the column names are right.

Comment: I added this and it works for the error described but I run out of memory. Is there a better way to merge after the below fix?

sessions_data.index.name = 'id'

Comment: this problem is beyond the original question, and you didn't provide any info to clarify what is happening. Anyways, check if you are making a cross join with your merge.

Comment: I know your got your solution, just mentioning for other people; I get the same  "# Check for duplicates" error with different reason. If the right data frame is empty you get the same error.